# Setting all DIVS on the same row to be the same height ... but different for each row

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I have a web page which is a series of DIVs such as:

```
    <div class="cell upcoming">
        <img src="stills/press/press-logo-c2e2.png" class="general"><p class="one">Panelist - Chicago Comic & Entertainment Expo 2013</p>
        <p class="two">[Panel Name TBD]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Date/Location:</b> [TBD] on April 26-28, 2013 at C2E2 (Chicago, Illinois)</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panelists:</b> [TBD]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Blurb:</b> [TBD]</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cell upcoming">
        <img src="stills/press/press-logo-wondercon-anaheim.png" class="general"><p class="one">Panelist - WonderCon 2013</p>
        <p class="two">[Panel Name TBD]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Date/Location:</b> [TBD] on March 29-31, 2013 at WonderCon (Anaheim, California)</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panelists:</b> [TBD]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Blurb:</b> [TBD]</p>
    </div>
```

The class "CELL" is set to 45% so it forms a two column 'table'.  The CSS is:

```
div.cell { position:relative; margin:2px; float:left; width:45%; text-align:justify; vertical-align:top; border:2px solid; padding:10px; border-radius:25px; -moz-border-radius:25px; }
```

Unfortunately, this has a habit of not ALWAYS being two populated columns because the left entry and right entry, on any given line, will be different heights, and that produces undesirable results (including looking really funny due to the disparity)

To combat this, I have a JQUERY which sets every single cell on the page to be the height attributable to the biggest cell:

```
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $("div.cell").each(function(){
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
    })
    $("div.cell").css("height",maxHeight);
```

What I really would like, however, is for each row to just match, rather than setting every cell to match.  In other words, if the web page is 1 2, 3 4, 5 6; I would rather have 1 and 2 be the highest height of 1 and 2.  3 and 4 would just be the highest of 3 and 4.  etc.

Is there a way to do this?

THANKS!

Comment: wrap each row in a DIV, remove top/bottom margin for `cell` and set height `100%`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each row in a div then

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $(".cell", this).each(function(){
      maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
  })
  $(".cell", this).css("height",maxHeight);
})
```

Try that. Not tested though

Comment: Paul Radich - That worked; thank you!   I have some pages I cannot wrap the rows in DIVS (they dynamically add or remove divs, which is why the class has two descriptions) but it will work for most of my pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning and learning and I solved the issue without having to set rows (which made the site maintenance unbearable due to the need to shift everything around each time a new cell was added):

```
$("div.cell:nth-child(even)").each(function(){
    var cellheight = $(this).height();
    var nextheight = $(this).next("div.cell").height();
    if ( cellheight > nextheight ) {
        $(this).next("div.cell").height(cellheight)
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).height(nextheight);
    }
});
```

Thanks all!